# Handle 403 Error - Google Maps w/ jQuery.getScript

Tags: jquery, google-maps, http-status-code-403

I am using jQuery.getScript to load google-maps dynamically with API-key.

```
jQuery.getScript("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=APPKEY&callback=initMap", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
   console.log(textStatus); //success
   console.log('Load was performed.');   
   console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
});


function initMap(){
var mapOptions = {          
center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.245178, 55.359438),           
zoom : 15,
mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
mapTypeControl : false   
};        
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),             mapOptions);      

}
```

The map loads and works fine now and logs "200" as `jqxhr.status`

With `getScript` API will I be able to handle 403 error, in case,  if it is thrown for **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**?

will I get `jqxhr.status=403` or should I use `fail(callback)` method ?

I am using Jquery v1.7.2

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  I don't think the loading of the _API_ will return OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

Comment: @geocodezip So, when this OVER_QUERY_LIMIT will be thrown ? I have added my initMap callback.Pls advice.

Comment: The OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error will occur When you call a web service or a javascript service that has a quota or a rate limit on it (i.e. the Geocoder or the directionsService) and you exceed that.

Comment: I have given the code `initMap` where I am just using `google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)`, so it shouldn't give me `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error anytime, right ?

Comment: @geocodezip , Pls confirm your statement on root-cause for OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.If I just use google.maps.LatLng(knownlat,knownlon) I should not get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT anytime, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$.getScript("ajax/test.js")
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
  console.log( textStatus );
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
  $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

Comment: I went through the documentation, but will I be able to handle the 403 error for Google-Map-API ? Any other links you have to handle 403 errors with getScript ?

Comment: Any 4xx status code clearly is an error, so that will be handled in the fail() handler.